# Custom Date format in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date-format

How to customize **Date** result like ***Wednesday, September 21, 2016*** in SQL Server 2008

Comment: YES, it can be varchar.

Comment: This should be done on the *client*, not the server.

Comment: Why it should not done on server?

Comment: Because the server has limited formatting functionality as you just saw, and you'll have to change the *query* each time you need to change the *client's UI*. On the other hand the client can format dates with a single `ToString` call *and* handle multiple cultures. What you asked is the long date format - `ToString("D")`. UI controls and reporting tools allow formatting of cells, labels etc so you can use whatever format you want *without* changing the query. You can also change the localization culture without even changing the UI formats

Comment: You are right. But, we are not using any culture specifics in our query. We are just customize the result according to our need in the query as you see under @gofr1 answer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, is this query still having some culture specifics faults?

Comment: The query *is* culture-specific. It's just that the culture comes from SQL Server itself. Besides, what happens when you need to change your report's format to use eg short dates ?

Comment: You are 100% right. I do it now in my C# code (client side) and having same out put. I'm returning just date from Sql Server and format it in my C# code like OneDayBeforeAnniversary.ToString("D") and got the same result. Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos. You're great man ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)+[DATENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx), you can put this into function and use in your query's:

```
DECLARE @date  datetime = GETDATE()

SELECT  DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@date)+', '+
        DATENAME(MONTH,@date)+' '+
        CAST(DATEPART(DAY,@date) as nvarchar(2))+', '+
        CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,@date) as nvarchar(4))
```

Output:

```
Wednesday, September 21, 2016
```

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Answer (score 0):

By using DATENAME:

```
SELECT datename(dw,getdate()) + ', ' + DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) 
         + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107), 9) AS [DayName, Month DD, YYYY]
```